# Sharepoint Designer - How to change Language

Tags: sharepoint-designer, language

How to change the language of Sharepoint Designer? I have Polish language, and I want to change it to English.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the English version from MSN for free. Here is a [link for 32-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573) and here is a [link for the 64-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24309) version. Make sure you select for Polish from the drop down menu. Since you didn't state, I am assuming you are using 2010. Here is for the [SPD 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) version. Hope this helps.

Comment: He has it in Polish, wants it in English

Comment: @RobertLindgren ... Wow, totally missed the direction, but the answer still works in reverse, lol. Thanks, will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint designer is part of office 2013. You have two options, you can either download English language pack for office or you can uninstall it and install an English version.