# How can we change language used in workflows in Sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint online site opened in Sharepoint designer 2013.

Site settings:

- Default language: Swedish
- Alternative language: English

When we add a workflow and start editing the workflow the workflow, all the actions and conditions are in Swedish, we want to develop in English.

Writing "Set" returns error message: "No result"

We changed the settings in Options | Choose editing language from swedish to english. But no change.

There is an other question on this site: [Sharepoint Designer - How to change Language](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112898/sharepoint-designer-how-to-change-language)  But that is how to get SharePoint Designer in English and that we have, it's the workflow that is causing problems for us.

Comment: All time is this same problem. The better ways is write always in English, but all time it's geting sometimes Your national language and English.

Comment: I can't find any information were it gets it's language  setting. Could be the Site setting but I can't see a valid reason for the designer to use the site setting. The steps in the workflow must be saved in a format that is language neutral. So it's should be a Intellisense setting for the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, SharePoint Workflow actions are dependent on the default language chosen during the creation of a new site.

**Fortunately**, I discovered a helpful workaround that allowed me to [**Change Workflow Actions language in SharePoint Designer**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/change-workflow-actions-language-in-sharepoint-designer/), which aligns with your scenario.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I don't have time to test the workaround right now. But it seems like a valid workaround. Hopefully the Sharepoint team will change the product so that the designer can choose the language in the future.